# purpose of enumeration?

Tags: c#

can someone please give me some examples where enumeration is used? i dont understand the concept. i mean both IEnumerable and enum?

have you used enum? please show me sample code

Comment: Do you mean `IEnumerable<T>` or `enum`?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  You mean a type that implements `IEnumerable(<T>)`, or like an `enum` with a set number of values?

Comment: @JaredPar, apparently he doesn't know it himself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Berry's post:

```
enum Title
{
Mr =1,
Mrs,
Miss
}
```

An ENUM is a user-defined type.  With the enumerator above, you can create as many instances of **Title** as you would like.

```
Title mine = Title.Mr; 
Title sister = Title.Miss;
etc.
```

An IEnumerable is an Array of enumerable types.  Most helpful to me using the foreach statement.

```
IEnumerable<string> list = new[] {"stringone", "string2", "stringthree"};

foreach (string s in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);  
}
```

will produce the following output:

```
stringone
string2
stringthree
```

Comment: "An IEnumerable is an Array": it is not an array, as you cannot use an indexer to access elements. You can only use `foreach` or the `IEnumerator<T>` interface.

Comment: It's a list which provides an iterator to iterate over a list... unlike an array, there are no defined indexed values.

Answer (score 8):

Anytime you have some kind of mapping between  magic values and meanings, then you should consider using an enumeration instead.  That way you can work with the enumeration constants instead of the magic values directly.

For example you could have something like this:

```
string getDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeek)
{
  if(dayOfWeek == 0)
    return "saturday";
  else if(...
}
```

Instead of using an int input parameter you could instead have an enumeration defined:

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
string getDayOfWeek(Days dayOfWeek)
{
  if(dayOfWeek == Days.Sat)
    return "saturday";
  else if(...
}
```

The first variant of the `getDayOfWeek` function is considered bad for 2 reasons:
1) It's hard to read, and hence harder to maintain and easier to make a mistake in your code
2) If you want to change Sat to now mean 1 you have a lot of code changes to make

You can [read more about enumerations here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

An enumeration is a type that can have multiple values.

Instead of declaring  a variable called color, and assigning it the string "blue" or "green"

you can create a enumeration, and define the colors blue,green etc.

This lets the compiler enforce restrictions if your app doesn't support red for example.

Otherwise you would get a runtime bug that would be more difficult to debug, and or a more lengthy error check routine.

**edit**

As dtb said, in some languages, enumerations are really just integers under the covers, so it is possible to assign numbers to them. If you are using them correctly, you will be doing this, but it is a valid point nonetheless.

Comment: `var c = (Color)99;` with `enum Color { Blue, Green }` is perfectly fine... not sure what you mean with enforcing restrictions here.

Answer (score 2):

An Enum is basically a list of related constants.

e.g

```
enum Title
{
Mr =1,
Mrs,
Miss,
Sir,
Madame
}
```

A full example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The `enum` keyword declares an *enumeration*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(VS.80).aspx

`Enum`s are types which contain a set of defined constants.  For example, you may have an enum defined like this:

```
public enum Months
{
  January = 1,
  February = 2,
  March = 3,
  ...
  December = 12
}
```

In your code, you may use this like the following:

```
Months birthMonth = Months.February;
```

`Enum`s are useful for when you have multiple, discrete values for a variable, and to increase the readability of your code.  For example, which of the following has a clearer intent?

```
File.Open("myFile.txt", 1, 3);
```

or

```
File.Open("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is an interface used to mark classes (usually collections) that have an enumerator; i.e. you can iterate through their elements.
[`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) is an interface that contains the methods to iterate through an enumerator; usually it is used to go through a collection's elements one at a time.  The [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) language construct is compiler magic to do all the necessary operations to iterate through an IEnumerator for you.
[`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) is used to define a list of related, named constants

Answer (score 1):

To tie descriptions to strings. For example, in your database you have a an 'Education Status' column which stores 0,1,2,3. They are tied to 'highschool', 'associates', 'bachelor' and 'masters'. In your application you make an enumeration to help keep these values straight.

```
enum int EducationStatus
{
    highschool,
    associates,
    bachelor,
    masters
}
```

so you can just say

```
if(yourRecord.EducationStatus == EducationStatus.highschool)
 ...
```

instead of 0. Also, this will help keep values uniform instead of always assuming that 0 means highschool, you use highschool and if it changes to 6, you make that change in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume you mean `enum` over `IEnumerable<T>`.

Enumerations are great for grouping a related set of named values in a semi-type safe manner.
My favorite example of a good use of an `enum` is to replace a boolean parameter.

For example the following code is equivalent but one is significantly more readable than the other

```
String.Compare(str1,str2,true);
String.Compare(str1,str2,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```